# Intsalling opencv on mac pycharm failed

Tags: macos, opencv, pycharm

I'm using python3.4 as my project interpreter in pycharm. I'm trying to install opencv and errors occur. It says "Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'User/me/.pyenv/version/3.4.1/bin/python3.4'. "
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention anything about what you tried to do to solve the problem so I'm going to start with the most obvious answer: `pip install --upgrade pip`.

If that does not help, I would suggest you to create an [Anconda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos), and point the Pycharm interpreter to it.

1. To be able to install and use OpenCV from anaconda, you have to install pip first. `conda install pip` will install pip in "/Users/you/anaconda2/envs/[your_env]/bin/".
2. Navigate to such folder and run `./pip install opencv-python`.
3. Go on Pycharm Preferences (press `cmd` + `,`) > Project:[your_project] > Project Interpreter and add "/Users/you/anaconda2/envs/[your_env]/bin/Python"

Then you should be good to go.